# value from the Visualforce page to controller is not getting passed

Tags: apex, visualforce

The value from the Visualforce page to controller is not getting passed. Why?

I have the following code and seems not passing the 'accountName' value to the controller.

```
public class ContactController {
    public String accountName {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> contacts {get; set;}

    public ContactController(){    
    }

    public void getContactUsingAccount(){
        System.debug('Account Name : '+accountName);
        contacts = [SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Phone FROM Contact where account.Name  = :accountName];
        System.debug('Contacts : '+contacts);
    }
}
```

and AccountVF page

```
<apex:page controller="ContactController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            Account Name : <apex:inputText value="{!accountName}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" reRender="outputContact,table1" action="{!getContactUsingAccount}">
                <apex:param name="accountName" assignTo="{!accountName}" value="{!accountName}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
        </apex:pageBlock>


         <apex:pageBlock id="table1">
            <b>Output Contact Details </b>
            <apex:outputText value="{!contacts}" id="outputContact" />
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c">
                <apex:column headerValue="FirstName" value="{!c.FirstName}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="LastName" value="{!c.LastName}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Phone" value="{!c.Phone}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Image
**I have only GenePoint single account, so it should show only single record,**

[image]

Comment: If I used that I see `Unknown method 'ContactController.ContactUsingAccount()': Markup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the param from the button. The input handles the assignment when the form is submitted

```
Account Name : <apex:inputText value="{!accountName}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" reRender="outputContact,table1" action="{!getContactUsingAccount}"/>
```